# Query Accounts based on Search String

Tags: jquery, apex, apex-sosl

I have a requirement where I have a search box on the vf page. Based on the search string I am returning accounts to the page. I have written a query which searches for account name based on the search string. But I want to compare the search string with all the fields in the object. Is there any possible way of achieving this...

Here is my Query...

```
String searchquery='Select Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE \'%'+searchString+'%\'';
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

To search across an object like that you want to use a [SOSL query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm) not SOQL.

```
String soslSearch = 'FIND \''+searchString+'\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Name)';
```

Also when doing queries in APEX using strings with user input make sure you consider escaping the inputs to [maintain security.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secure-serverside-development)